# OpenVPN blocks Spotify internet access

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, spotify

I have setup an OpenVPN split tunneling so that i can choose which traffic goes through my VPN (via a SOCKS5 proxy).

Here are my network interfaces
[image: Here are my network interfaces]

When i connect with OpenVPN, windows tells me that i have no internet access, although i can still access through the vpn and with my regular connection, so i did not bother to investigate.

However, the Spotify app does not work in this configuraton. I can look for songs but cannot play them. I have to disconnect OpenVPN for the Spotify app to work

I do not know how to start fixing this.

Here is my OpenVPN Configuration

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote vpnsite.web port_number

cipher AES-256-CBC
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
remote-cert-tls server
ping 10
ping-restart 60
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288

auth-user-pass file_userpass.txt
ca vpn.crt

service vpnnameopenvpn
block-outside-dns

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA

route-nopull
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route vpn_ip 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: I assume that you are using the spotify app from Microsoft Store... you could try to recreate this behaviour with an app which also needs internet access and is installed though the microsoft store. If the behaviour is the same, then I would assume that the problem is related to an authentication error of windows because windows is thinking you have no internet access

Answer (score -1):

Spotify's wonderful Nannies at work confirming your location... Change your Proxy settings in Spotify to "autodetect settings" that should do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).